# export import browser complaint cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

This Meteor app has a template event that maks a `Meteor.call`, and is causing browser error `Cannot find module 'server/plateCheck.js'`. The file responsible is:

```js
//app/imports/api/vehicles/methods.js

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { Vehicles } from './vehicles.js'
import { plateCheck } from "../server/plateCheck.js"; //<<<<<<<<<< 

Meteor.methods({
    'extractPlateData': function (plate) {
        console.log('method called: ', plate)
        plateCheck(plate)
    }
)},


//app/imports/api/vehicles/server/plateCheck.js

import {Vehicles} from '../imports/api/vehicles/vehicles.js'

const plateCheck = async (plateNumber) => {...}
module.exports = plateCheck;
```

`meteor list` includes ecmascript                    0.15.1

Why is this and isn't the export/import correct as stated? How to get read of the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your relative path is wrong. The `server` folder is in the same directory as `methods.js`, so you'll need to import

```
import { plateCheck } from "./server/plateCheck.js";
```

Or you can make all imports absolute:

```
//app/imports/api/vehicles/methods.js
import { plateCheck } from "/imports/api/server/plateCheck.js";

...

//app/imports/api/vehicles/server/plateCheck.js
import {Vehicles} from '/imports/api/vehicles/vehicles.js'
```

Comment: I tried both for no avail. `Cannot find module './server/plateCheck.js'`, and `Cannot find module '/imports/api/server/plateCheck.js'` Do I need to move files around for better application folder structure?

Comment: Moving the file out of the server folder in `imports/api/vehicles` fixed the problem but is it secure?

Comment: yes, it's secure. Things in `/imports` don't get published to the client unless you import them explicitly.